# displaying svn projects contained in the repository not working

Tags: svn, windows-xp

I've just installed SVN and created a project for Test named TestProject which was succefully created .
 when I try to display the projects contained in my SVN repository, with the following address : `svn://localhost:3690/TestProject` the browser can't open it.
Is the problem with the address I'm using or something else ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

> svn://localhost:3690/TestProject the browser can't open it

Browser (web-browser?!) can't handle `svn://` protocol, SVN != Web. you **must** to use for svnserve'd repositories only SVN-clients (TortoiseSVN with it's Repository Browser, for example)

Comment: Thanks @Lazy Badger :) I just would like to know if it's necessary to install SVN on every client, or it's enough to install only SVN-client on them ? My situation is a server with many clients which will collaborate on a project using Eclipse, and commit their changes to the server.

Comment: @mounaim - everybody, who want to see project tree - must have (any) SVN-client